# How do I test react Request parameters with jest?

Tags: reactjs, request, jestjs

I have a get request in react:

```
  axiosInstance.get(`${apiUrl}`, {
    params: {
      ...callParameters,
    },
  })
```

Which I can then mock with:

```
      mockAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
        Promise.resolve({
          data: { records: mockResponse }
        })
      );
```

But how can I check what params the API was called with?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the mocked function calls using:

```js
axiosInstance.get.mock.calls[0][1]
```

where the first index in `calls` is the number of the call and the second index is the argument index (`0` would be the URL, `1` should be the config object).

See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockcalls